# Accessibility for custom back buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, accessibility

I am using a custom `UIButton` as a back button in a View Controller. This back button is not in a `UINavigationBar`, it is simply treated as a view that floats over the top of the content, whose action triggers a pop (but could just as easily call a delegate method that dismisses the view controller.

I want this back button to be treated as a proper navigation back button by the accessibility feature in iOS, rather than a regular button that is labelled 'back'.

At WWDC '16 an Apple accessibility engineer told me that this could be very important for users (presumably because certain accessibility devices use this info). He could tell that I hadn't implemented it correctly by the way the label was spoken in VoiceOver ("back. button" vs "back-button" ... you can hear the difference yourself if you use voiceover on a standard `UINavigationController`'s nav bar 'back' button compared to a regular UIButton whose `accessibilityLabel` is set to `NSLocalizedString("Back", nil)`.

Unfortunately, I can't for the life of me remember how to fix this (or at the very least, didnt take notes :/ ).

Accessibility Inspector gave no special different accessibility properties when pointing at a navbar back button (and crashed repeatedly).

So... what am I missing? Is it some accessibility element/container trait? Or the type of the button? Or is it some UIKit magic based on the fact it's in a navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

First off, functionally, there is no difference in functionality between the two.  The way you word it suggests that you are worried about how it functions, you should not be.  The important part here is that it announces correctly.  The accessibility apis do not care HOW your button functions, so whether or not you are calling a delegate method or dismissing a view controller is completely inconsequential.

Therefore, let's focus on how the element is spoken to the user.  The things that control how an element in iOS is spoken are as follows.

Accessibility label: Or text, for buttons that have an inherent text value.  EX: The title of a button, or text within a text field.  Though, notably, if you override the accessibility label, this text will also be overridden!

Accessibility Hint: Additional text to describe the consequences of performing an action.  Not always required, but helpful in some circumstances.

Accessibility Traits: A pre-defined set of roles a UI Element can play.  These have varying results when applied to elements.  SOme change the way an element is announced (like buttons and links) and some warn the Accessibility APIs about certain behaviors like whether or not an element plays a sound, so VoiceOver can react accordingly.  SO NOW!  Let's break down the "Proper" mark up for a "back" button, and where the elements of the announcement come from.

```
AccessibilityLabel = "Back"
OR
Title/Text = "Back" and AccessibilityLabel = nil
AccessibilityTraits = [Button]
AccessibilityHint = "Goes back to the previous screen."
```

**I'm going to consider the hint optional in this case.

VoiceOver Announcement:

> Back (short pause) #button (long pause) Goes back to the previous
>   screen.

Where #button = the localized word for button.  In this case, just button.  But it is worth noting that by utilizing the button trait, you are programmatically telling the app that you have a button, and allowing VoiceOver to figure out how to announce it! When it comes to localization, predicate vs subject first languages, etc... this is very important.  Also, programmatic determination of roles is a requirement from WCag, and while not formally required on native apps, is still a best practice.  Remember, we are not only concerned with how VoiceOver responds to your control, but also other potential ATs as well.  Making sure each piece of information is stored in its correct place is very important.  You might be able to trick VoiceOVer into behaving properly, but how will your app render for a BrailleBoard?

An alternative INCORRECT markup would be placing all of this information in the accessibility label:

```
AccessibilityLabel: "Back, button"
Traits: none
Hint: none.
```

This would announce VERY similar, but subtly different (and obviously I omitted the hint in this case).  Someone experienced with the accessibility APIs would certainly notice, and definitely someone using an AT aside form VoiceOver... such as a Braille Board.

Comment: Thanks. And apologies if I wasn't clear in my text, but my question was not about the use of traits/labels to specify buttons - I understand that and it has been implemented correctly. The question is about the specific situation of the back button in a navigation controller vs a generic UIButton. They report differently in voice over, and I was wondering why that was, and if (as an Apple engineer told me) there was a functionality difference for certain accessibility tools, such as a BrailleBoard or a Switch.

Comment: The safest thing for clarity is to include code samples or gists.

Comment: I'm afraid I dont see what code would help? As I wrote above, a generic UIButton (`let btn = UIButton(); btn.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Back", nil)`) will speak the phrase "Back. Button." (note pause between Back and Button). The back button (actually UIBarButtonItem) in a navigation bar (created simply by pushing a viewController onto a UINavigationController) will say "Back Button" (no pause). Not sure what other code to supply.

Comment: Code allows one to go in with accessibility inspector and inspect for bugs/other unexpected causes of this behavior.  Me writing my own version does not help this.  Otherwise, you have all of the information you need to come to conclusions yourself.